# County Shapefile goes into body of Water

Tags: qgis, county

I am trying to map three counties in QGIS with a layer of census tracts on top. The county border is in white and the census tracts are in green. Is there a way to not show the county border but leave the county names? It appears the census tract body of land matches what I see on California maps. It appears these three counties have borders that go into the water. [image]

Answer (score 4):

You can change the style of the county layer to either have transparent borders (and eventually a transparent fill), or to be 100% transparent.

Both settings affect the rendering but preserve the labels.

[image: Transparent with label]

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think of that. Thank you

Comment: It's more efficient to set the pen style to "no pen" rather than make it transparent

Comment: @BarrySmith, please take a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers to learn what to do when someone answers your question. Tks.